# Problema em chamar um metodo em um jlabel

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Bom estou tentando fazer uma aplicação em 2 telas a primeira para setar os valores e a segunda tela para sair os valores 
a primeira [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

está funcionando normal
Codigo:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package calculadoraimc;

import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

/**
 *
 * @author SpiriT
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        TextField_Peso = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        TextField_Altura = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Peso_Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Altura_Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        TextField_Nome = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Nome_Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JFundo = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Calculadora de IMC");
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 255));
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 600));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 600));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Calcular");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);
        jButton1.setBounds(190, 490, 240, 60);

        TextField_Peso.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                TextField_PesoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(TextField_Peso);
        TextField_Peso.setBounds(260, 290, 180, 30);
        getContentPane().add(TextField_Altura);
        TextField_Altura.setBounds(260, 330, 180, 30);

        Peso_Label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 2, 24)); // NOI18N
        Peso_Label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        Peso_Label.setText("Peso");
        getContentPane().add(Peso_Label);
        Peso_Label.setBounds(170, 290, 110, 30);

        Altura_Label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 2, 24)); // NOI18N
        Altura_Label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        Altura_Label.setText("Altura");
        getContentPane().add(Altura_Label);
        Altura_Label.setBounds(160, 330, 110, 30);
        getContentPane().add(TextField_Nome);
        TextField_Nome.setBounds(260, 370, 180, 30);

        Nome_Label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 2, 24)); // NOI18N
        Nome_Label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        Nome_Label.setText("Nome");
        getContentPane().add(Nome_Label);
        Nome_Label.setBounds(160, 370, 110, 30);

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/calculadoraimc/ftc.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(130, 90, 410, 150);

        JFundo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/calculadoraimc/fd.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        JFundo.setText("jLabel1");
        getContentPane().add(JFundo);
        JFundo.setBounds(0, 0, 612, 644);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String nome = TextField_Nome.getText();
    double peso = Double.parseDouble(TextField_Peso.getText());
    double altura = Double.parseDouble(TextField_Altura.getText()); 
    IMC i = new IMC(nome, peso, altura);

     TextField_Nome.setText(" ");
     TextField_Peso.setText(" ");
     TextField_Altura.setText(" ");

     new NewJFrame1().setVisible(true);
     dispose();
    }                                        

    private void TextField_PesoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel Altura_Label;
    private javax.swing.JLabel JFundo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Nome_Label;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Peso_Label;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TextField_Altura;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TextField_Nome;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TextField_Peso;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

já a segunda que mostrar os gets está dando um error:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package calculadoraimc;

/**
 *
 * @author SpiriT
 */
public class NewJFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private IMC i;
    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame1
     */
    public NewJFrame1() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JFundo = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jLabel2.setText(i.getNome());
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(210, 280, 250, 14);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/calculadoraimc/ftc.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(130, 60, 420, 210);

        JFundo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/calculadoraimc/fd.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        JFundo.setText("jLabel1");
        getContentPane().add(JFundo);
        JFundo.setBounds(0, 0, 625, 644);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel JFundo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

codigo do error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at calculadoraimc.NewJFrame1.initComponents(NewJFrame1.java:41)
    at calculadoraimc.NewJFrame1.<init>(NewJFrame1.java:18)
    at calculadoraimc.NewJFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:116)
    at calculadoraimc.NewJFrame.access$000(NewJFrame.java:14)
    at calculadoraimc.NewJFrame$1.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:58)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at calculadoraimc.NewJFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:108)
    at calculadoraimc.NewJFrame.access$000(NewJFrame.java:14)
    at calculadoraimc.NewJFrame$1.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:58)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 12 segundos)
```

Answer (score 0):

**NullPointerException** um erro muito comum em Java. Esse erro ocorre quando estamos trabalhando com valores null, e queremos referencia-los para fazer algo.
Um exemplo, suponhamos que tenhamos um classe pessoa, como essa:

```
 public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;

    public void andar(){
        System.out.println("ANDANDO");
    }
}
```

Ao Realizar a instancia de pessoa com:

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
```

Podemos acessar os métodos publicos do objeto Pessoa, uma vez que o compilador conhece o tipo do objeto.

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
p.andar();
```

Porém, quando não instanciamos o objeto pessoa, e declaramos apenas o objeto como.

Pessoa p;
p.andar();

Um NullPointerException será lançado, uma vez que o compilador não conhece o método andar(), pois não sabe qual a instancia do objeto.

Esse é apenas um exeplo do NullPointer e que acho que esteja acontecendo com seu código, existem outras situações, porém mesmo provavel.

Surigo que debug seu código, afim de encontrar onde estão esses objetos nulos.